# Convert '6E+007' into Decimal

Tags: python, exponential

I have a python function that checks if the value passed is a valid number. The values passed are in string format.

```
def is_valid_numeral(text_to_check):
    '''Check if passed value is a valid numeral figure'''
    try: 
        float(text_to_check)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

A value like `6E+007` is passed and this function returns True which is correct.

After the above function, I need to save the passed figure into a Decimal field. So I run a `format_decimal` function as below

```
def format_decimal(value, decimals): 
    '''Format a value to "n" decimal places
    http://mkaz.com/solog/python/python-string-format.html
    '''
    try:
        if decimals == 2:
            value =  int(value)/100
            return "{:.2f}".format(int(value))
    except ValueError:
        raise
```

At this point, it fails with the error:

```
`Value Error: Invalid literal for int() with base 10:6E+007`
```

Since this really is a valid figure just in a different notation, is there a function that can convert this type of value for me and then pass it through the `format_decimal` function?

Comment: But it IS a number.. It's only another notation to write it.

Comment: It would still return true, so what's the point of the exercise?

Comment: In <0>: int(6E+007)
Out<0>: 60000000

Comment: @aIKid I've edited the question to reflect the real problem. So its still a valid amount. Issue is, after this validation, I need to convert it to decimal notation

Comment: @Yohann what do you mean? I've ran `int(6E+00` and it still fails with `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6E+007'`

Comment: @lukik It's valid. You forgot the `)`. Try `$ python -c "print int(6E+007)"`

Comment: @Yohann no it's not. the value here is not `6E+007` which is a float, but `"6E+007" which is a string.

Comment: @lukik i've updated my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking the validity by converting to `float`, but actually doing the conversion with `int` - the discrepancy is causing your problems.

The `decimal` module is the best way to convert large format numbers.

```
>>> int(decimal.Decimal('6E+007'))
60000000
```

You don't want to do a double conversion to `float` then `int` because that can result in rounding errors.

```
>>> int(float('1e23'))
99999999999999991611392L
>>> int(decimal.Decimal('1e23'))
100000000000000000000000L
```

Comment: +1 for the rounding observation. So `int(decimal.Decimal(value))` is ideal because it gives you the correct output without rounding off.

Comment: @lukik, an `int` in Python potentially has better precision than a `float` which is why I added the warning. You'll only see this when you're dealing with values over 9e15.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm.  You changed the original question; the way it is *now* it should be trivial:  since you're *checking* for whether `float()` works now, just be consistent with that:  stop using `int()`!  That is, change to this:

```
def format_decimal(value, decimals):
    try:
        if decimals == 2:
            value = float(value)/100
            return "{:.2f}".format(value)
    except ValueError:
        raise
```

But the code is still confused:

1. Why are you dividing by 100?  Do you really want, e.g., `"1234"` to change into `"12.34"`?
2. What if `decimals` *isn't* 2?  Then your `format_decimal()` does nothing:  it "falls off the end" and so returns `None`.
3. Catching an exception and immediately re-raising it is the same as not bothering to catch it to begin with.  That is, the `try/except` structure, as written, does nothing except complicate the code.

It would really help if you gave exact examples of input strings and their expected output strings.

### Generalizing

Try this?

```
def format_decimal(value, decimals=2):
    from decimal import Decimal
    # divide value by 10**decimals; this is just scaling
    value = Decimal(value).scaleb(-decimals)
    return "{:.{d}f}".format(value, d=decimals)
```

That allows specifying the scaling factor (`decimals`).  Here's sample input/output.  If anything isn't what you want, say exactly what it is that you do want:

```
for v in "1", "1234.5678", "1.2e6":
    for d in range(4):
        print repr(v), d, "->", repr(format_decimal(v, d))
```

and the output:

```
'1' 0 -> '1'
'1' 1 -> '0.1'
'1' 2 -> '0.01'
'1' 3 -> '0.001'
'1234.5678' 0 -> '1235'
'1234.5678' 1 -> '123.5'
'1234.5678' 2 -> '12.35'
'1234.5678' 3 -> '1.235'
'1.2e6' 0 -> '1200000'
'1.2e6' 1 -> '120000.0'
'1.2e6' 2 -> '12000.00'
'1.2e6' 3 -> '1200.000'
```

Comment: **1**. The use case is that am required to convert all the values into 2 decimal places **2**. The `decimals` parameter in that function is under my control. Currently I only need 2 decimal places but in the future if I need 3 decimal places, I'll add an `elif decimals == 3`... **3**. Got a link on the best way to handle this? I've actually never really grasped error handling in python completely :-(

Comment: *Please* give exact examples of input strings and their expected output strings.  I know you're trying, but your English descriptions are unclear.  For example, do you - or do you not - want to produce the string `"12.34"` for the input string `"1234"`?  I have no idea.

Comment: @TimPeters Hey Tim, you should join [the python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) :).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple. `6E+007` is not an integer notation, but a float notation.

Instead of `int('6E+007')`, use float first:

```
int(float('6E+007'))
```

Or, use the decimal module:

```
import decimal
int(decimal.Decimal('6E+007'))
```

Also, IMO if you want the number to have two decimal places, you should use float instead, since the value of an integer cannot contain any fractional component, and will always be like that. For example, `int('1.5')` will always be `1`, not 1.5.

So just use:

```
value = float(value/100) #Well, i'll keep the division here,
# since i don't know what it's about.
return ":{.2f}".format(value)
```

Hope this helps!