# Decimal number with 10 digits

Tags: python, decimal

I'm doing some calculation with python. But I troubling with decimal numbers. my code is like:

```
from decimal import *

x = 0.0000001582
y = 0.00000020
z = 1000

a = 0.000000100
b = (x+y)/z

result = x + b

print result
```

My results comes like this `1.585582e-07` .
I want simple decimal number up to 10 digits. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert '6E+007' into Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532556/convert-6e007-into-decimal)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
print '{0:.10f}'.format(variable)
```

Where the 10f is the digits you want to go and variable is what you want to print

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope works for you: https://repl.it/ODuB

```
from decimal import *

x = 0.0000001582
y = 0.00000020
z = 1000

a = 0.000000100
b = (x+y)/z

result = x + b

print format(result, '.10f')
```